# Use cursor to loop and Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an insert statement which includes a sub-query to determine the next value in a column that is used as an Identity but is sadly an nvarchar(20) type (not my db by the way).

I need to be able to generate the next incremental number for the AssetNo field. I can determine the next number by casting as a numeric but when inserting multiple records they all get the next value. I therefore assume that I need to add a cursor but have little or no experience with these.

My code is as follows:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbAsset
    (
        AssetUID,
        AssetNo,
        LocationParentID,
        LocationID,
        LocationDescription,
        Quantity,
        UnitTypeID,
        ElementID,
        LifeExpectancy,
        InstalledDate,
        OutsideHour,
        Status,
        BookingResource,
        IsSystem,
        IsPartOfSystem,
        AssetClassID,
        LastUpdate,
        LastUpdateUser,
        SystemConfidence,
        UserConfidence,
        IsOriginalComponent,
        ClientCode,
        ApplicationResource
    )
           SELECT
               NEWID() AS Expr1,
           (
               SELECT
                   MAX(CASE
                           WHEN ISNUMERIC(AssetNo) = 1
                           THEN CAST(AssetNo AS INT)
                           ELSE NULL
                       END) + 1 AS 'AssetNo'
               FROM tbAsset
           ) AS Expr2,
               Template_Structure_Location.Location_Type,
               Template_Structure_Location.Client_Location_Ref,
               Template_Structure_Location.Location,
               Template_Survey.Quantity,
               tbUnitType.UnitTypeID,
               dbo_Item.CLIENT_ITEM_REF,
               dbo_ProcedureX.LIFE_EXPECTANCY,
               NULL AS Expr3,
               '0' AS Expr4,
               '0' AS Expr5,
               '0' AS Expr6,
               '0' AS Expr7,
               '0' AS Expr8,
               '2' AS Expr9,
               GETDATE() AS Expr10,
               'PDS' AS Expr11,
               '100' AS Expr12,
               '100' AS Expr13,
               '0' AS Expr14,
               '0' AS Expr15,
               '0' AS Expr16
           FROM dbo_Item
           INNER JOIN Template_Survey ON dbo_Item.Itemref = Template_Survey.ItemRef
           INNER JOIN Template_Structure_Location ON Template_Survey.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_LOCATION_REF = Template_Structure_Location.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_LOCATION_REF
           INNER JOIN Template_Structure ON Template_Structure_Location.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF = Template_Structure.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF
           INNER JOIN Template_Details ON Template_Structure.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF = Template_Details.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF
                                          AND Template_Structure.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF = Template_Details.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF
           INNER JOIN dbo_ProcedureX ON dbo_Item.Itemref = dbo_ProcedureX.Itemref
           INNER JOIN tbUnitType ON dbo_Item.IPF_Element = tbUnitType.UnitDescription
           LEFT OUTER JOIN tbAsset AS tbAsset_1 ON Template_Survey.K2ref = tbAsset_1.AssetNo
           WHERE(Template_Details.Status = N'Signed Off')
                AND (Template_Details.StatusME = N'Signed Off')
                AND (Template_Survey.K2ref IS NULL)
                AND (dbo_ProcedureX.Replacement = 1);
END;
```

Comment: Tip o f today: table aliases!

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting such a big query.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012 - apologies for the oversight

Comment: Just go through https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Comment: In above your code i m not found any key value where i could be stored in cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Let's trim this down to a basic assumption:

```
insert into t2 (ID, Descrip, AssetNo)
select ID,
       Descrip,
       (
       SELECT MAX(AssetNo) + 1 from T1
       )
from T1
```

So now, let's try and solve this simpler problem (if your DBMS supports CTEs and window functions):

```
with CTE as
(
select ID, Descrip, row_number() over(order by ID) as RN
from T1
)
insert into t2 (ID, Descrip, AssetNo)
select ID, Descrip, (select max(AssetNo) from T1) + RN
from CTE
```

Comment: @Rahul I thought `NEWID()` was MS SQL only

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no one but it's not about MySQL ... hope you understand

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand where this should be added in the context of my query.